# Unable to run GUI applications in Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux, application

When attempting to run programs in Kali Linux, notably insomnia and Postman, the app runs with no errors, but the screen is a frame containing whatever is behind it. Running as root, reboots, and re-installs had no changes.

[image: Frame screenshot]

Comment: I would recommend you read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and improve your question. We can't help you unless you provide information that we can work with.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like insomnia and Postman are not present in the standard Kali repositories. Since you installed insomnia using `apt`, this means you've added non-Kali repositories to Kali.

From [the official web pages of Kali Linux](https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories/):

> [...] adding other operating system’s repositories into Kali (such as trying to put Ubuntu on Kali), will break your installation. This is the single most common reason why Kali Linux systems break. ​ If any guides are telling you to do anything else than the above, this is unofficial advice, and completely not supported by Kali Linux. More often than not, users in this case end up doing a reinstall after learning this lesson. ​ ​ ​

Although you haven't added a base repository of some other Linux distribution, you should note that neither insomnia nor Postman are claimed to be supported by Kali. It looks like you found out they indeed won't work "out of the box".

This might be because they need some X11 fonts or other resources that are guaranteed to be present in Debian/Ubuntu by dependencies between standard packages, but Kali apparently has different versions of those packages with stripped-down dependencies. If you want to make it work, you'll have to try and find out what are the actual technical requirements of these applications and which packages on Kali might satisfy those requirements.